# Multiple variables for a logical expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I wanted to know if what I did is even on the correct path for how this question is worded. How can you have two variables when it's dealing with a single unhappy person? I'm guessing the third way will just be using De Morgan’s Laws for quantifiers?

> Translate each of these statements into logical expressions in three different ways by varying the domain and by using predicates with one and with two variables.
>
> - There is a person in your school who is not happy.

My first solution:

> S(x) statement “x is in my school” and H(x) statement “x is happy”
> ∃x(S(x) ∧ ￢H(x))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to say that $\exists x\in \hbox{Human Race}$ s.t. $S(x)\wedge \sim H(x)$.  What you have is basically correct.  Just bound the $x$ in some set to give context.

Comment: What did it mean by the using predicates with one and with two variables? It sounded like it wanted something like ∃x∀y(statements)

Comment: The clause "$x \in \text{Human Race}$" is a set-theoretical, not strictly speaking logical. (Typically $\in$ is not admitted as a logical symbol)

Comment: All logical arguments must somehow be bounded by a universe of discourse.  You could say $\exists \hbox{a human}  x$ s.t.... http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UniverseOfDiscourse